# Map numerical values in one column to categorical values in another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a dataframe with numerical values

| score |
| --- |
| 16.0 |
| 49.0 |
| 55.0 |
| 65.0 |
| 77.0 |
| 89.0 |
| 98.0 |

I want to create another column in the same dataframe with categorical values based on the numerical values.

| score | names |
| --- | --- |
| 16.0 | low |
| 49.0 | low |
| 55.0 | low |
| 65.0 | avg |
| 77.0 | avg |
| 89.0 | high |
| 98.0 | very high |

Answer (score 0):

```
scores = df['score'].tolist()
names = []
for i in range(len(scores)):
    if scores[i] < 60.0:
        names.append('low')
    elif scores[i] < 80.0:
        names.append('avg')
    elif scores[i] < 90.0:
        names.append('high')
    else:
        names.append('very high')
df['names'] = names
```